# not getting any kind of margin in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was creating a template today using bootstrap. suddenly My grids are not getting any margin between them.

my markup are pretty simple:

```
<div class="container" div style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 box">
            <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 box">
            <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 box">
            <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 box">
            <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I didn't face anything like it before. please help me.

Comment: You do not need te repeat `col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3`. The "smallest": `col-sx-3` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no margins between the columns in bootstrap but there is padding. When you set the background-color to white, that creates a background for the padding too which is why it looks continuous and not separated.

Add this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="white-box">
     ...
  </div>

</div>
```

With `.white-box` whatever you want such as `background-color: white;`

Comment: No problem, here to help :D

Answer (score -1):

The Bootstrap grid-system does not add any margins - instead it adds a padding inside the columns. You could build something like this:

```
<div class="container" div style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12 box">
                <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12 box">
                <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12 box">
                <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12 box">
                <p>flacon</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I also removed your many col-XX-3 classes as stated in my comment. For mor details see [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any .col-md- class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg- class is not present.

Comment: nesting columns without row?

Comment: bootstrap documentation wants you: "...only columns may be immediate children of rows" not vice versa. At least I couldn't find something like this ;)